# Swift / Operation with Float

Tags: ios, swift

I have been experiencing something while calculating with floats which I do not understand, maybe somebody can explain the difference between these two operations and the results:

```
for var i = 10; i < 20; i++ {
   //Assuming i = 11
   var result1:Float = Float(i/10) //equals 1
   var result2:Float = Float(i)/10 //equals 1.1
}
```

I stumbled upon that because I expected result1 to return 1.1 and spent some time searching for the mistake until I understood the syntax must be like for result2

Is it because in Float(i/10) the inner operation (i/10) will always return an integer before it gets converted to a Float?

Any explanation appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is right, `i/10` where `i: Int` will **always** return an integer.

It is then converted to a floating point number, but `Float(1) == 1`.

The second statement converts `10` to a Float implicitly before performing the division, hence return `1.1`

Answer (score 0):

Since `i` is an `integer` and 10 is an `integer`, the result of the division is approximated to an `integer` too.
If you want to see the result as a `float` one of the 2 should be a `float`.
This rule probably comes from C programming language. This is the so called *Truncation towards zero*.
I've found [something](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/18189/two-common-mistakes-in-floating-point-arithmetic-in-c/) about C, but rules stills applies for swift.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have got the right point. Because due the order of parenthesis first perform the (11/10) operation and it returns a round figure int value and lost the portion (.1) after point.

Answer (score 0):

Just an addendum, you can also get result2 with:

```
var result3 = Float(i/10.0)
```

Also an FYI, C style for loops are [going away in Swift 3.0](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0007-remove-c-style-for-loops.md)